# Replace duplicated time index and fullfilling by time interpolation

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, reindex

I have a dataframe with a wrong time stamp

The time index is wrong, instead of being sampled in periods of 1 min contains duplicated indexes with multiples of 10minutes

```
2021-08-01 00:00:00
2021-08-01 00:00:00
2021-08-01 00:00:00
2021-08-01 00:00:00
...
2021-08-01 00:10:00
2021-08-01 00:10:00
....
2021-08-01 00:20:00
2021-08-01 00:20:00
... and so on
```

The desired result after the postprocessing should be

```
2021-08-01 00:00:00
2021-08-01 00:01:00
2021-08-01 00:02:00
2021-08-01 00:03:00
...
2021-08-01 00:10:00
2021-08-01 00:11:00
...and so on
```

I have been trying with pandas.index functions to fullfill the duplicated indexes with nans and then interpolate to 1min but without success

Any hint?

Answer (score 2):

Yo can add timedeltas by 1 minutes by counter by duplicated indices by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
print (df)
                     b
a                     
2021-08-01 00:00:00  1
2021-08-01 00:00:00  1
2021-08-01 00:00:00  1
2021-08-01 00:00:00  1
2021-08-01 00:10:00  1
2021-08-01 00:10:00  1
2021-08-01 00:20:00  1
2021-08-01 00:20:00  1

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df.index += pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), 'Min')
print (df)
                     b
2021-08-01 00:00:00  1
2021-08-01 00:01:00  1
2021-08-01 00:02:00  1
2021-08-01 00:03:00  1
2021-08-01 00:10:00  1
2021-08-01 00:11:00  1
2021-08-01 00:20:00  1
2021-08-01 00:21:00  1
```